# Splitting a string of tuples into tuples

Tags: python

I have a string of tuples where each tuple is separated by a comma. How do I split it into a list of tuples?

For example, I'd want to split this string:

```
"(2,3) (3, 4) ( 5, 4)"
```

Into this array of tuples:

```
[(2,3) , (3,4),(5,4)]
```

Note that there may be spaces within tuple (like `"(3, 4)"`) so `str.split()` then using `eval()` will not work.

Comment: What if you added opening and closing braces and then did a safe eval?

Comment: Your example input string only has commas inside the tuples but not between the tuples. Is this your actual string? `"(2,3) (3, 4) ( 5, 4)"`

Comment: Your sample input does not have commas between the tuples, it has spaces.

Comment: Yes the input has spaces between the tuples. But lists in python have commas between values

Comment: Where is that input coming from to begin with?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `re.split` with `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import re, ast
result = [ast.literal_eval(i) for i in re.split('(?<=\))\s(?=\()', "(2,3) (3, 4) ( 5, 4)")]
```

Output:

```
[(2, 3), (3, 4), (5, 4)]
```

Note that `ast.literal_eval` is much more secure that the builtin `eval`, as `ast.literal_eval` does not blindly evaluate whatever is passed to it, and instead checks if the input is a valid Python datatype.

However, the above will not work if the tuples in string form are not separated by a space i.e `"(2,3)(3, 4)(5, 6)"`. In that case, you can create a small parser:

```
class Parse:
  def __init__(self, _input, _start=''):
    self.data, self.group, self.content = _input, _start, []
    self.parse()
  def __iter__(self):
    yield from map(ast.literal_eval, self.content)
  def parse(self):
    _val = next(self.data, None)
    if _val is not None:
       if _val == '(':
         r = Parse(self.data, _start="(")
         self.content.extend(r.content)
         self.data = r.data
       elif _val == ')':
         self.content.append(self.group+')')
       else:
         self.group += _val
       self.parse()

final_result = list(Parse(iter("(2,3)(3, 4)(5, 6)")))
```

Output:

```
[(2, 3), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If these are always tuples of two digits like you claim, just use `re.findall`:

```
>>> out = re.findall(r'(\d+),\s*(\d+)', s)
>>> out
[('2', '3'), ('3', '4'), ('5', '4')]
```

If you need these as integers:

```
>>> [tuple(map(int, i)) for i in out]
[(2, 3), (3, 4), (5, 4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

One other way may be:

- First you can split by comma and get list of all digits.
- Then, use `zip` such that you separate list of numbers with skipping every other number one starting from initial position and other from second position using `::2` and `1::2`.

---

```
my_str = "(2,3) (3, 4) ( 5, 4)"
# getting list of digits only
all_numbers = [int(ch) for i in my_str.split(',') for ch in i if ch.isdigit()]
# using zip to convert into tuples
result = list(zip(all_numbers[::2], all_numbers[1::2]))
print(result)
```

The output is:

```
[(2, 3), (3, 4), (5, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub` to replace the spaces in between tuples with `,` and then add braces and feed to `literal_eval` to interpret into a Python data structure:

```
>>> s="(2,3) (3, 4) ( 5, 4)"
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> import re
>>> literal_eval("["+re.sub(r'(?<=\))[ \t]*(?=\()',',',s)+"]")
[(2, 3), (3, 4), (5, 4)]
```

Which works even with no spaces between the tuples:

```
>>> s="(2,3)(3, 4)( 5, 4)"
>>> literal_eval("["+re.sub(r'(?<=\))[ \t]*(?=\()',',',s)+"]")
[(2, 3), (3, 4), (5, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a list comprehension if you don't want to use any libraries or eval:

```
a="(2,3) (3, 4) ( 5, 4)"
[tuple(map(int,e.split(','))) for e in a.replace(' ','')[1:-1].split(')(')]
```

Output:

```
[(2, 3), (3, 4), (5, 4)]
```

This works by removing all the spaces and taking out the first and last parenthesis, splitting by `)(`, and converting the remaining strings to tuples with ints in them